# kubernetes ABAC via resource labels

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, rbac, abac, k8s-rolebinding

In K8s Is there any way to access the resources within a namespaces basis labels that are attached to them.

RBAC access in K8's is primarily handled from a namespace level, so there are difficulties in adequately segmenting access to an app level.
What we want to implement is restricted access to a particular team's resources basis the label that is attached to them

Comment: Why not just give team/app their own namespace and use rbac?

Comment: The apps belonging to different teams need to interact with eachother so that might make it a bit more complicated if put in separate namespaces

Comment: No. If they expose services they can still interact with each other, just that the DNS name will be slightly different.

Comment: If you really want to proceed with abac, look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/abac/. Though I foresee that you can run into situations where things are made for rbac and won't work with abac.